# Do a SELECT in MYSQL to return the remainder of an ID COUNT/8

Tags: mysql, division

I would like to know how to do a Query in `MySQL` to get the remainder of the `ID_COUNT / 8`.

Here's an example table:

```
 ID (INT)  | PRODUCT ID | TIME
  1        |     14     | 09:34:00
  5        |     26     | 09:47:00
  5        |     01     | 09:58:00
  1        |     02     | 10:10:00
  2        |     63     | 10:36:00
  4        |     59     | 10:47:00
  3        |     18     | 11:00:00
  1        |     27     | 11:15:00
  5        |     36     | 11:38:00
  1        |     44     | 09:34:00
  5        |     55     | 09:47:00
  5        |     14     | 09:58:00
  1        |     24     | 10:10:00
  2        |     54     | 10:36:00
  4        |     44     | 10:47:00
  3        |     54     | 11:00:00
  1        |     64     | 11:15:00
  5        |     14     | 11:38:00
```

What i would like to do here is, every time a new row is inserted, I want to get the `COUNT` of that `ID` (for example for the `ID=5` it would be 6), and them divide that number by 8 (6/8) and then get the remainder of that division.

I'm using PHP by the way, if there's no way of doing it only with MySQL.

Thanks in advance, any question fell free to ask!
Miguel.

Comment: Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but why 8? Is 8 a number you will always want to use to divide you count by, or just in this case?

Comment: do you want to do the entire calculation in the query or will it be ok if count is extract using query and then calculated with php code?

Comment: GolezTrol - Yes i was only getting the count, but I already manage to do it thanks to yAnTar's reply.

Comment: Ross Wilson, well 8 was just for this exemple, but yes it will always be the same number, don't know witch one yet!

Comment: saran banerjee - If possible I would like to do it in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [MOD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) function

Query for you example

```
SELECT COUNT(1) MOD 8 AS result
FROM `table`
WHERE id=5
```

Query for common example

```
SELECT id, COUNT(1) MOD 8 AS result
FROM `table`
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Thanks yAnTar it did the trick! Didn't know the MOD function. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MOD(cnt, 8) FROM (SELECT COUNT(ID) cnt FROM mytable GROUP BY ID)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, didn't knew the mod function, used it and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mod()` function:

```
select mod(count(*), 8)
from t
where id = @Last_Id
```

The `id` is not auto incremented, so you cannot use `last_inserted_id()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, didn't knew the mod function, it worked!